# Definitions of relative compactness

Tags: compactness

Per definition, a subset $A$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is relatively compact if and only if its closure $\overline{A}$ is compact.
That means that any sequence in $\overline{A}$ contains a subsequence that converges in $\overline{A}$. Does that imply that $\partial A$ is compact?

According to an alternative definition, $A$ is relatively compact if any sequence in $A$ contains a subsequence convergent in $X$. How do you derive from this that $\partial A$ is compact?

In other words, how can you show that both definitions are equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

The boundary of $A$ is defined as
$$
\partial A=\overline{A}\cap\overline{A^c}.
$$
So $\partial A$ is a closed subset of a compact set, and hence compact.

Let $\{x_n\}\subset\partial A$. Since $\partial A\subset\overline{A}$ and $\overline{A}$ is compact, then there exists a subsequence $x_{n_k}\to x\in\overline{A}$. However,
$\{x_{n_k}\}\subset\partial A$, and since $\partial A$ is closed and $\{x_{n_k}\}$ convergent to $x$, then $x\in \partial A$. Thus every sequence in $\partial A$ possesses a convergent subsequence with limit in $\partial A$. Hence, $\partial A$ is compact.

Comment: But how do you get there from the alternative definition of relative compactness?

Comment: @user1975053 I only use the fact that $\overline{A}$ is compact and $\overline{A^c}$ is closed.

Comment: Ignore the first definition. How can you get from the second definition to the compactness of $\partial A$?

Comment: if any sequence in A contains a subsequence convergent in $\overline A$, can there be no sequences in  $\partial A$ without an in $\partial A$ convergent subsequence?

Comment: @user1975053 See my further explanation.

Comment: My problem is, the compactness of $\overline A$ is not part of the second definition of relative compactness of $A$. How do you get there from this second definition? (I have edited my question accordingly).